# Why would only half a radiator heat up?

Tags: radiator

I'm having some trouble with a radiator.  It doesn't bleed well, often not letting either air or water come out of the valve.  And sometimes, only half of the radiator will be hot (well, warm).  I was given to believe that all of the water entering the radiator would travel through the entire thing, heating it equitably.  Seems strange to me.

Any explanations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it doesn't bleed well this means the system is is not pressurized enough (if there are any radiators higher up they won't be heating at all) add some water to the system and try to bleed again

or there could be an airlock blocking the water flow; to fix this turn off all radiators except the one affected and let the pump force the water through

Comment: or a pipe block with segiment, if so get the pipe replace and/op the system flushed